# C# Executing a query and getting data out of an Access Database (accdb) without using ACE.OLEDB

Tags: c#

I'm writing a WPF application.

Trying to use the normal method of getting a connection returns an error similar to: "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

ACE.OLEDB has never been installed on this machine so this error makes sense.

I'm trying to create this application in a way so that our users won't need to contact IT to have the application installed. Getting IT involved is a no go situation and the project will be abandoned.

Another team has an Access database (accdb) that I want my application to extract information (only read, no insert or update). I talked to the team and they won't convert this database back to an earlier version (mdb).

After my research I assume that installing ACE.OLEDB without using Admin privileges is impossible. Because of this and my application requirement of not requiring admin privileges I need to start looking for "Mutant"/Dirty solutions that don't involve ACE.OLEDB.

I tried using power-shell but I'm getting the same problems as I had with C# (requires IT to install ACE.OLEDB).

I have two potential solutions. One write a VBA script that opens up the database and dumps a query result into a file. My C# application would call this VB script and then parse the created file.

The second option is to create a new Access process using Process.Start(fullFilePath) and somehow pass the command to execute a query and somehow pass the results back to the executing application (either via a method return or first to a file).

How would you get the data out?

Is there a way for C# to duplicate the DB file and convert it from (accdb -> mdb)?

This is the second question I ask that is very similar.

[C# Connecting to Access DB with no install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103947/c-sharp-connecting-to-access-db-with-no-install?noredirect=1#comment102599120_58103947)

The difference between the two (to prevent this is a duplicate question) is that in the previous question I was looking for ways to install ACE.OLEDB without admin privileges while here I'm just looking for any other work around.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround. It uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access found in NuGet.

```
    var accApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
    accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@tests.DatabasePath);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database cdb = accApp.CurrentDb();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset rst =
cdb.OpenRecordset(
    "SELECT * FROM Users",
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot);
    while (!rst.EOF)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rst.Fields["username"].Value);
        rst.MoveNext();
    }
    rst.Close();
    accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
    accApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get @Mandelbrotter answer to work you must add the following nugets.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access note the version. At August 2023 it was version 15.0.4420.1018. The important part is the 15.

I installed Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao but I am not sure if its needed.

You also need a Microsoft.Interop nuget and you need it to be the same version as the interops. For example if the Microsoft.Office... are 15.## then you need to install the version 15.0.#### the 16.0.### will not work.